How has this limit of the sequence been achieved?
I am reading a section from a book where some basic/introductory material on Delta functions has been presented. The author has explained the Delta sequences through the usage of Fourier series representation of a given piecewise function. I was able to derive this Fourier series representation of the function: $\delta_n(x) = \frac{1}{2L} + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{m\pi} sin\left (\frac{m\pi}{nL}  \right )cos\left ( \frac{m\pi x}{L} \right )$
Now, the author says that by taking the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$ of the Fourier series representation, the Delta function is $\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2L} + \frac{1}{L}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} cos\left ( \frac{n\pi x}{L} \right )$. Can someone please tell how has this limit been achieved ?
Edit: $L = 1/n$

You might want to use the fact that $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Thanks. That provided the much needed hint. I used the L'Hospital rule to move further ahead. However, in the presence of limit, I don't understand how the summation sign for $n$ ranging from 1 to $\infty$ has been used.

I am thinking that it's a question of representation and the author chose to use "n" instead of "m" which would have also been valid.

That is correct thinking, although notation is a tad misleading, since $L=\frac{1}{n}$.
